# Fedex SmartPost Invalid HubId for Developer Account

Tags: web-services, fedex

I'm creating an shipment for Fedex SmartPost and it always returns to me the following message:

```
"Code":"8670","Message":"Invalid Smart Post Hub Id"},
"Code":"2505","Message":""USPS_DELIVERY_CONFIRMATION" was added to the smart post special services."
```

I'm using a developer account for Fedex WebServices. What Hub should I use for creating an smartpost ? Right now I have used all from the online documentation.

Answer (score 7):

All accounts in the FedEx test environment use the SmartPost HubId of ‘5531’ like so:

```
<ns:SmartPostDetail>
<ns:Indicia>PRESORTED_STANDARD</ns:Indicia>
<ns:AncillaryEndorsement>ADDRESS_CORRECTION</ns:AncillaryEndorsement>
<ns:HubId>5531</ns:HubId>
</ns:SmartPostDetail>
```

Concerning the Indicia, use ‘PARCEL_SELECT’ for anything that’s 1-70 lbs.  Anything less than 1 lbs. use ‘PRESORTED_STANDARD’.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  Thanks 5531 worked for me in FedEx dev environment.

Answer (score 5):

As sad as it can be the issue relies on Fedex Developer account. Your developer account will not be able to use SmartPost. It is necessary an real account so it can have an HubId attached to it. Learned this today after calling Fedex Technical support.

I would assume that if it is a developer account it can use any HubId, but as it seems the assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Further clarification just learned from Fedex Support : The HubId will be assigned to the account when SmartPost is provisioned, and is not necessarily the closest geographically to the shipping location.

Comment: I can unfortunately confirm that they still don't have a development environment for SmartPost which is odd